# Fileprovider always throws IAE

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fileprovider, internal-storage, android-internal-storage

I looked at all the answers on StackOverflow and there no answer for me.

Same error for real device and emulators.

Fileprovider always throws IllegalArgumentException

There is Manifest

```
<application
   ...

    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        android:exported="false"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/filepath"/>
    </provider>

</application>
```

There is filepath.xml

```
<paths>
<files-path
    name="logs"
    path="logs/" /></paths>
```

And there is code which always throw exception

```
        final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

        File file = new File(logger.getFileName());
        Uri uri = null;
        try {
            uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(), BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, file);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

logger.getFileName() - returns real file name for example: "logs_22032019.txt"

What I already tried:
Changes in Manifest such as:
   android:authorities="com.realname.of.package"
Changes in filepath.xml

```
name="logs"
```

- 1) same name of file 2) just /

  path="logs/"
- 1) . 2) / 3) full path 4) files 5) /files 6) files/ e.t.g

What I'm noted - there is really the path of files:

```
/data/user/0/com.app.realname/files/log.txt
```

But FileProvider in it goes to:

```
"log.txt" -> "/data/data/com.app.realname/files/log.txt"-->
```

**NOTE:** I need only INTERNAL storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> logger.getFileName() - returns real file name for example: "logs_22032019.txt"

That is not a valid filesystem path. It is a valid filename, but it does not say where that file is supposed to be on the device.

This is your `FileProvider` configuration:

```
<files-path
    name="logs"
    path="logs/" />
```

For that, a `File` that would work is:

```
File file = new File(getFilesDir(), "logs/"+logger.getFileName());
```

> there is really the path of files... But FileProvider in it goes to

Those are the same filesystem location, for the primary device user.

Comment: It works!  Thank You a lot! I hate my inattention. So much time lost.